# pysnmp: How to send a trap with time of trigger information

Tags: pysnmp, snmp-trap

I am using pysnmp to generate v3 traps

How should to send time of trigger information with the trap

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use the [sysUpTime](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3418) object to convey the SNMP system *uptime* information.

Alternatively, you could a special custom OID dedicated for carrying time information (add it via `.addVarBinds()`).

```
from pysnmp.hlapi import *

errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(
    sendNotification(
        SnmpEngine(),
        UsmUserData('usr-md5-des', 'authkey1', 'privkey1'),
        UdpTransportTarget(('demo.snmplabs.com', 162)),
        ContextData(),
        'trap',
        NotificationType(
            # your trap type
            ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.5.2')
        ).addVarBinds(
             # sysUpTime in hundredths of a second
             ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0'), 123456)
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: By default pysnmp is sending the sysUptime . I can use that I believe.

I am using

' 
ntfOrg.sendVarBinds(
             self.snmpEngine,
             'my-notification',  # notification targets
             None, '',  # contextEngineId, contextName
             rfc1902.NotificationType(
                 trapName,
                 objects={('PARTITION-MIB', k): v for k, v in eventvals.items()}
                 ).resolveWithMib(mibViewController)
          )
'

Comment: That's right, pysnmp provides `sysUpTime` if the user does not. The reason is that `sysUpTime` is one of the two mandatory OIDs in the TRAP message.